# How can I compute $\max\{v^Tx :\, v \in \mathbb{R}^n \textrm{ and } \|v\| = 1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, normed-spaces

If $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, how can I compute this?

$$\max\{v^Tx :\, v \in \mathbb{R}^n \textrm{ and } \|v\| = 1\}$$

here, $\|\cdot\|$ is euclidean norm.

Comment: What is the norm? Euclidean?

Comment: Euclidian / L2 norm.

Comment: $v^Tx$ is a sum - I would want as little cancelling of terms out as possible.

Comment: The max value is $\|x\|$ by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality

Comment: If ||x|| is the max what must v be?

Comment: @bananaboy the max is attained in the Cauchy Schwarz inequality when the two vectors in question are a scalar multiple of each other.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value is $||x||$ because you can observe that

$v^tx=||v||||x||\cos(\theta(v,x))=||x||\cos(\theta(v,x))$

Thus the maximum value there is only for $v=\lambda x$ but $||v||=1$ so

$$|\lambda| =\frac{1}{||x||}$$

This means that

$$\sup_v v^tx=\frac{x^t}{||x||}x=\frac{||x||^2}{||x||}=||x||$$

Comment: What is ((,))? Why is it not just ()? Also what is the sup notation you are using?

Comment: @atn $\theta(v,x)$ is the angle individuated by the two vectors $v$ and $x$, so it depends by $v$ and $x$. The sup notation is the standard notation of the sup and it is a more synthetic notation of  what you wrote.

Comment: I'm honestly a little confused because I don't know what "sup" is. Also how did you deduce the maximum value is for where $v= \lambda x$?

Comment: @atn because that function  has maximum value when cos(\theta) is equal to 1, so for $\theta=2k\pi$ that means $v$ and $x$ are linear dependent